# Dealing with NULL values and EMPTY strings in UNION of two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, union

I want return records from two database tables when a record differs in at least one of the fields.

I have written a query for it using the `UNION` operator.  It is working absolutely fine.

However, I want to treat NULL and '' (empty string) as the same value.

For example, all entries have a field `Email-ID` having value `NULL` in one table and `''` in the other table.

Using the query I have, it is showing these two are different.  I want these two values to be treated the same.  I have around 15 such fields.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ISNULL or COALESCE

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.NULLABLEFIELD,'') FROM A
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(B.NULLABLEFIELD,'') FROM B
```

Comment: Thanks. Just got it before your reply.
Your reply made me confident about the solution.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I used UNION to get that problem solved.

Now what I want is to treat "raj" and "Raj" as different string values.
Can I do it?

Comment: Change collation type to Latin1_General_CS_AS